# Netlogo BehaviourSpace weird Output and Multiple Runs

Tags: netlogo

For some weird reason the behaviorSpace in netlogo runs the same value pairs model multiple times even though repetitions are 1. I can't understand why. The output file in table format looks like this. I don't know what's up with double quotes.

```
BehaviorSpace results (NetLogo 5.2.0)                                                                       
/home/abhishekb/new_models/basic/try4.nlogo                                                                     
experiment1                                                                     
10/26/2015 02:34:28:770 +0530                                                                       
min-pxcor   max-pxcor   min-pycor   max-pycor                                                           
-7  7   -7  7                                                           
[run number]    knt k   threshold   scale   [step]                                                  
16  0   75  0.1 1   2535                                                    
7   0   54  0.1 1   0   8715                                                
5   0   47  0.3 1   0   9374                                                
10  0   61  0.1 1   0   8841                                                
"22 0   89  0.1 1   0   3664"8" 0   54  0.3 1   0   12001"  0   40  0.1 1   0   10727
2"  013"    0   68  0.1 1   0"22    0   89  0.1 1   0   4449                        
128"    0   103 0.1 1   0   2805                                                
4   0   47  0.1 1   0   1200119"    0   82  0.1 1   0   12001"1 0   40  0.1 1   0   12001
3"                                                                      
26" 0   96  0.3 1   0   4800                                                
9"  0   103 0.3 1   0   43321"  0   82  0.6 1   0   7385                        

31  0   110 0.1 1   0   2976                                                
1"  0   40  0.1 1   0   12001                                               
4"  0   89  0.6 1   0   6389                                                
25  0   96  0.1 1   0   7517                                                
26  0   96  0.3 1   0   5479                                                
9""27"  0   96  0.6 1   0   6117                                                


28  0   103 0.1 1   0   2219                                                
29  0   103 0.3 1   0   6411                                                
30  0   103 0.6 1   0   5693                                                
31  0   110 0.1 1   0   3985                                                
78  500 61  0.6 1   0   9720                                                
79  500 68  0.1 1   0   6067                                                
80  500 68  0.3 1   0   6795                                                
81  500 68  0.6 1   0   8305                                                
82  500 75  0.1 1   0   4416                                                
83  500 75  0.3 1   0   5742                                                
84  500 75  0.6 1   0   7399                                                
85  500 82  0.1 1   0   5306                                                
86  500 82  0.3 1   0   5388                                                
01"                                                                     
87  500 82  0.6 1   0   6869                                                
88  500 89  0.1 1   0   12001                                               
89  500 89  0.3 1   0   5097                                                
90  500 89  0.6 1   0   6478                                                
91  500 96  0.1 1   0   2275                                                
92  500 96  0.3 1   0   4693"   500 96  0.6 1   0   6395                        
94"94   500 103 0.1 1   0   12001                                               
95  500 103 0.3 1   0   3984                                                
96  500 103 0.6 1   0   5440                                                
97  500 110 0.1 1   0   1893                                                
98  500 110 0.3 1   0   37299"  500 110 0.6 1   0   5275                        
100 750 40  0.1 1   0   12001                                               
101"    750 40  0.3 1   0   12001                                               
102 750 40  0.6 1   0   12001                                               
"
103"""  750 47  0.1 1   0   11911                                               
"
104"""  750 47  0.3 1   0   12001                                               
105 750 47  0.6 1   0   11821                                               
750"    54  0.1 1   0   12001                                                   
107 750 54  0.3 1   0   8703                                                
811108" 750 54  0.6 1   0   10099                                               
5"                                                                      
,61"    0.1 1   0   12001                                                       
110 750 61  0.3 1   0   7453                                                
0111"   750111" 750 61  0.6 1   0   9051                                            
112 750 68  0.1 1   0   12001                                               
    68  0.3 1   0   12001
```

BehaviourSpace Code:

```
@#$#@#$#@
NetLogo 5.2.1
@#$#@#$#@
@#$#@#$#@
@#$#@#$#@
<experiments>
  <experiment name="experiment1" repetitions="1" runMetricsEveryStep="false">
    <setup>check-setup-percent
file-write-values</setup>
    <go>go</go>
    <final>write-to-file</final>
    <timeLimit steps="12000"/>
    <exitCondition>count inboxturtles with[exit = 1 and exited = false] = 0</exitCondition>
    <steppedValueSet variable="knt" first="0" step="250" last="2500"/>
    <steppedValueSet variable="k" first="40" step="7" last="110"/>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="threshold">
      <value value="0.1"/>
      <value value="0.3"/>
      <value value="0.6"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="scale">
      <value value="1"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
  </experiment>
</experiments>
@#$#@#$#@
@#$#@#$#@
default
0.0
-0.2 0 0.0 1.0
0.0 1 1.0 0.0
0.2 0 0.0 1.0
link direction
true
0
Line -7500403 true 150 150 90 180
Line -7500403 true 150 150 210 180

@#$#@#$#@
1
@#$#@#$#@
```

Comment: What program did you open the output csv file in? If Excel, can you please open it with a text editor so that we can see what it actually looks like?

Comment: @JenB Thanks for reply! Please check the file at this https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B16PrXUjs69zbldRSXg0c05malk . It weirdly seems to have a lot NUL values which makes difficult paste here.

Comment: Is this a bug I figure it out at all?

Comment: Okay, that file is definitely corrupt. After the introductory text, it should have 6 values (in " " and separated by ,) on each line. The first line of values is fine, then there's a blank line and the following lines have 7 values interspersed with long lines and blank lines, then it fixes itself again for a while. Normally BehaviorSpace handles `stop` clauses etc very smoothly. Do you actually have a bug in your model where you are, for example, dividing by 0 under some conditions?

Comment: I can't tell from what you've told us so far whether BehaviorSpace is producing a mangled file, or whether it's just getting mangled when you try to transmit it to us. I'll assume the latter unless you can definitively confirm the former.

Comment: Have you deleted something? You had text format available a few hours ago but it's now missing again. Do your experiment again with a small number of parameter combinations. Create the csv table as usual. Then RENAME the file to have the TXT extension rather than the CSV extension. Post the output of that instead of the csv output you have. We need to see what BehaviorSpace is actually producing, not whatever it gets mangled to when you open the file.